# Возникают ошибки при работе кода Python

Tags: python

Возникают подобные ошибки, как это исправить?
Shadows name 'x' from outer scope

Shadows name 'y' from outer scope

Shadows name 'z' from outer scope

Shadows name 't1' from outer scope

Shadows name 't2' from outer scope

Shadows name 't3' from outer scope

Parameter 'process1' value is not used

Parameter 'process2' value is not used

Parameter 'process3' value is not used

Parameter 'process4' value is not used

Parameter 'process5' value is not used

Parameter 'process6' value is not used

Parameter 'res_list' value is not used

Shadows name 'res_list' from outer scope

Local variable 'process_list' value is not used

Local variable 'res_list' value is not used

Shadows name 'res_list' from outer scope

Local variable 'current_res' value is not used

Local variable 'st' value is not used

Local variable 'current' value is not used

Parameter 'event' value is not used

Shadows name 'x' from outer scope

Вот сам код:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- config: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
import queue
import threading
import time


class QueueThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self) -> None:
        print(f'Старт потока {self.name}')
        process_queue()
        print(f'Завершение потока {self.name}')


def process_queue():
    while True:
        try:
            x = ps_queue.get(block=False)
            process1 = idx[x]
            y = ps_queue.get(block=False)
            process2 = idx2[y]
            z = ps_queue.get(block=False)
            process3 = idx3[z]
            t1 = ps_queue.get(block=False)
            process4 = idx4[t1]
            t2 = ps_queue.get(block=False)
            process5 = idx5[t2]
            t3 = ps_queue.get(block=False)
            process6 = idx6[t3]
        except queue.Empty:
            return
        else:
            print_factors(x, y, z, t1, t2, t3, process1, process2, process3, process4, process5, process6, res_list)

        time.sleep(1)


def print_factors(x, y, z, t1, t2, t3, process1, process2, process3, process4, process5, process6, res_list):
    try:
        for g in results:
            process_list = g[x]
    except KeyError:
        res_list = []
    current_res = []
    st = time.time()
    try:
        begin = drop_list[x]
    except KeyError:
        begin = 1
    for i in range(begin, x + 1):
        current = time.time()
        if i == x:
            del idx[x]

        elif y == 24:
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние STATE - 1:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[x]}, PRIOR - {x} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t1}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние STATE - 2:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[x]}, PRIOR - {x} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t1}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние STATE - 4:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[x]}, PRIOR - {x} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t2}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:2 перешел в состояние STATE - 1:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[y]}, PRIOR - {y} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t2}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:2 перешел в состояние STATE - 2:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[y]}, PRIOR - {y} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t2}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:2 перешел в состояние STATE - 16:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[y]}, PRIOR - {y} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t2}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(t2)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:2 завершил работу, и перешел в состояние STATE - 8:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[y]}, PRIOR - {y} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t2}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:3 перешел в состояние STATE - 1:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[z]}, PRIOR - {z} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t3}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:3 перешел в состояние STATE - 2:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[z]}, PRIOR - {z} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t3}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:3 перешел в состояние STATE - 4:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[x]}, PRIOR - {z} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t3}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние STATE - 16:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[x]}, PRIOR - {x} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t1}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(t1)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние STATE - 8:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[x]}, PRIOR - {x} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t1}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:3 перешел в состояние STATE - 16:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[z]}, PRIOR - {z} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t3}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(t3)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:3 перешел в состояние STATE - 8:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[z]}, PRIOR - {z} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t3}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            break
        elif x == 24:
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние STATE - 1:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[x]}, PRIOR - {x} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t1}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние STATE - 2:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[x]}, PRIOR - {x} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t1}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние STATE - 16:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[x]}, PRIOR - {x} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t1}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(t1)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:1 завершил работу, и перешел в состояние STATE - 8:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[x]}, PRIOR - {x} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t1}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:2 перешел в состояние STATE - 1:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[y]}, PRIOR - {y} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t2}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:2 перешел в состояние STATE - 2:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[y]}, PRIOR - {y} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t2}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:2 перешел в состояние STATE - 16:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[y]}, PRIOR - {y} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t2}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(t2)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:2 завершил работу, и перешел в состояние STATE - 8:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[y]}, PRIOR - {y} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t2}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:3 перешел в состояние STATE - 1:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[z]}, PRIOR - {z} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t3}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:3 перешел в состояние STATE - 2:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[z]}, PRIOR - {z} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t3}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:3 перешел в состояние STATE - 16:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[z]}, PRIOR - {z} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t3}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(t3)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:3 завершил работу, и перешел в состояние STATE - 8:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[z]}, PRIOR - {z} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t3}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            break
        elif z == 24:
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние STATE - 1:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[x]}, PRIOR - {x} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t1}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние STATE - 2:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[x]}, PRIOR - {x} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t1}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние STATE - 4:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[x]}, PRIOR - {x} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t1}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:3 перешел в состояние STATE - 1:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[z]}, PRIOR - {z} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t3}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:3 перешел в состояние STATE - 2:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[z]}, PRIOR - {z} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t3}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:3 перешел в состояние STATE - 16:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[z]}, PRIOR - {z} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t3}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(t3)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:3 завершил работу, и перешел в состояние STATE - 8:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[z]}, PRIOR - {z} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t3}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:1 перешел в состояние STATE - 16:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[x]}, PRIOR - {x} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t1}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(t1)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:1 завершил работу, и перешел в состояние STATE - 8:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[x]}, PRIOR - {x} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t1}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:2 перешел в состояние STATE - 1:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[y]}, PRIOR - {y} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t2}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:2 перешел в состояние STATE - 2:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[y]}, PRIOR - {y} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t2}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:2 перешел в состояние STATE - 16:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[y]}, PRIOR - {y} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t2}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(t2)
            term.insert(END, f'Процесс PID:2 завершил работу, и перешел в состояние STATE - 8:\n'
                             f'Класс приоритета: {class_grades[y]}, PRIOR - {y} \n'
                             f'Время выполнения процесса - {t2}с \n \n'
                             f'----------------------------------------------------------------\n \n')
            time.sleep(1.5)
            break


def entry_get(event):
    global idx, cm_list, ps_queue
    command = en1.get()
    term.insert(END, f'# {command} \n')
    cm_list.append(command)
    en1.delete(0, 'end')
    if command == 'exit':
        root.destroy()
    elif command.startswith('add1 '):
        parts = command.split(' ', maxsplit=3)
        num = int(parts[1])
        proc = float(0.5)
        idx[num] = proc
        ps_queue.put(num)
    elif command.startswith('add2 '):
        parts = command.split(' ', maxsplit=3)
        num = int(parts[1])
        proc = float(0.5)
        idx2[num] = proc
        ps_queue.put(num)
    elif command.startswith('add3 '):
        parts = command.split(' ', maxsplit=3)
        num = int(parts[1])
        proc = float(0.5)
        idx3[num] = proc
        ps_queue.put(num)
    elif command.startswith('addt1 '):
        parts = command.split(' ', maxsplit=3)
        num = int(parts[1])
        proc = float(0.5)
        idx4[num] = proc
        ps_queue.put(num)
    elif command.startswith('addt2 '):
        parts = command.split(' ', maxsplit=3)
        num = int(parts[1])
        proc = float(0.5)
        idx5[num] = proc
        ps_queue.put(num)
    elif command.startswith('addt3 '):
        parts = command.split(' ', maxsplit=3)
        num = int(parts[1])
        proc = float(0.5)
        idx6[num] = proc
        ps_queue.put(num)
    elif command == 'clear':
        term.delete(0.0, END)
    elif command == 'start':
        thread1 = QueueThread('A')
        thread1.start()
    elif command == 'list':
        term.insert(END, f'Список приоритетов, состовляющих алгоритм планирования \n')
        for i in idx:
            term.insert(END, f'{i} \n')
        for i in idx2:
            term.insert(END, f'{i} \n')
        for i in idx3:
            term.insert(END, f'{i} \n')
    elif command == 'help':
        term.insert(END, f'"add1 PRIOR" - добавляет уровень приоритета PID1. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"add2 PRIOR" - добавляет уровень приоритета PID2. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"add3 PRIOR" - добавляет уровень приоритета PID3. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"addt1 TIME" - добавляет время выполнения процесса PID1. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"addt2 TIME" - добавляет время выполнения процесса PID2. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"addt3 TIME" - добавляет время выполнения процесса PID3. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"list" - выводит список приоритетов, для алгоритма планирования. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"clear" - очищает терминал. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"help" - выводит список команд. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"start" - запускает алгоритм планирования. \n')
        term.insert(END, f'"exit" - выход. \n')
    else:
        term.insert(END, f'{command} -- неизвестная комманда, используйте "help". \n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    idx = {}
    idx2 = {}
    idx3 = {}
    idx4 = {}
    idx5 = {}
    idx6 = {}
    res_list = []
    results = []
    drop_list = {}
    cm_list = []
    ps_queue = queue.Queue()
    for x in idx:
        ps_queue.put(x)
    for y in idx2:
        ps_queue.put(y)
    for z in idx3:
        ps_queue.put(z)
    for t1 in idx4:
        ps_queue.put(t1)
    for t2 in idx5:
        ps_queue.put(t2)
    for t3 in idx6:
        ps_queue.put(t3)

    class_grades = {24: "Real time class",
                    13: "High class",
                    10: "Above normal class",
                    8: "Normal class",
                    6: "Below normal class",
                    4: "Idle class"}

    root = Tk()

    root.geometry('570x400')
    root.title("Подсистема управления процессами с алгоритмом планирования на основе абсолютных приоритетов")
    root.resizable(False, False)

    lb1 = Label(text='Командная строка:', width=0)
    lb2 = Label(width=0)
    en1 = Entry(width=65, bg='#333333', fg='white')
    term = Text(bg='#333333', width=65, height=19, fg='white')

    en1.bind('<Return>', entry_get)
    en1.bind('<Button-1>', lambda x: print(idx))

    lb1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10, padx=5)
    lb2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
    en1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
    term.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=10)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: добавьте полный текст ошибок

Comment: добавил все ошибки

Comment: Это похоже не ошибки, а предупреждения IDE или линтера (pylint, mypy, flake8 и т.д.). При работе кода какие-то ошибки возникают?